# Bower is installed and in path, but not recognized

Tags: bower-install

I have installed bower with npm and added the npm location to my path.  But when I try to execute a bower command, I still get a bower is not recognized error message.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So even though npm was in the PATH variable, it wasn't being seen.  If I used the full path to bower, it worked. So I took npm out of the path and added it back in and now it works.